# How can I see a unified log of changes to a set of files in perforce?

Tags: perforce

I'm new to perforce, coming from a history of cvs->svn->git.  I'm having a difficult time seeing a compact representation of the most recent changes impacting a set of file.  For instance, if I go to a directory and type:

```
% p4 filelog .
```

It doesn't do anything useful.  More interesting is

```
% p4 filelog *
```

However this shows me the change history of every file individually.  I'd rather see a unified view of changes in a format showing: change number, submit message, changed files for the most recent N submits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can almost get this with:

```
p4 changes -lt [file[RevRange]...]
```

This will show you the changelists that affected the files in question. It doesn't show which files were affected by each change, however. You could write a script that took the output of `p4 changes` and used `p4 describe -s` to get the file listing for each changelist.

Note that `p4 changes` includes pending changes by default. Add `-s submitted` for only submitted changelists. There are other flags to narrow it down further, like `-u username` and `-m max` (to limit the number of changelists returned -- it returns newest first).

Comment: This is good enough for me.  If I need more info about a change I can dig deeper with `p4 describe`.

Answer (score 0):

To list the files that have changed between your @start,@stop times,

`p4 -c WORKSPACENAME files //Path/You/Care/About/...@2013/03/20:13:40,@2014/06/016:17:00`