# Is there a single Perforce command to display a list of all the check-ins to a file/dir along with the list of files that changed and the description?

Tags: perforce

`p4 changes -l ...` shows us the list of check-ins and the description, but it doesn't show the list of files that were modified in the check-in. Is there a way to do that in *one command*, without the need to create a wrapper script that combines the output of another command like `p4 describe` or `p4 file`?

In Subversion, I can do this by running `svn log -v`.

Comment: See this question for a similar request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443638/how-can-i-see-a-unified-log-of-changes-to-a-set-of-files-in-perforce

Comment: Best I know is, in Unix, `p4 changes | cut -f2 -d" " | p4 -x- describe -s`.  But this sounds like it's not what you want.

Comment: You can do a `p4 describe` with multiple arguments, so that `p4 describe 1 2 3` would work.  The trick is somehow expanding argument to include all changelists.

Answer (score 4):

The 'files' command can do what you're looking for. An easy way is:

```
p4 files //...@=<changelist>
```

That example will list the files modified by that changelist, under the view specified.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "describe" command to get the description of a changelist, along with the files affected.

For example, `p4 describe -s <changelist>` will describe the changelist, and the "-s" will prevent it from displaying file diffs.

Answer (score 0):

One liner, list all changes made to a branch, with description and list of affected files, without showing the diff. Thanks to a combination of answers. Works on windows with Unix utils

```
p4 changes -s submitted //depot/xxx/yyy/zzz/... | grep -o "^Change [0-9]*" | cut -f2 -d" "  | p4 -x- describe -s
```

Output:

> Change 1753385 by user@clientspec on 2019/03/08 06:29:44
>
> Changing the world
>
> Affected files ...
>
> ... //depot/xx/yy/zz.h#6 edit
>
> Change 1751752 by name@clientspec on 2019/03/05 15:24:00
>
> I made a change to a file
>
> Affected files ...
>
> ... //depot/xx/yy/zz.h#3 integrate